# "message" : "Invalid requests[0].updateCells: Attempting to write column: 26, beyond the last requested column of: 25"

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am getting this error when updating 30 columns on a google spreadsheet using Google Sheets API v4.

**Code to update the headers of columns of a google spreadsheet with date value as string:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 10, 01);

// # of days
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    String varDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date : " + varDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    values.add(new CellData().setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setStringValue(varDate)));

    requests.add(new Request().setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
        .setStart(new GridCoordinate().setSheetId(0).setRowIndex(0).setColumnIndex(i))
        .setRows(Arrays.asList(new RowData().setValues(values))).setFields("*")));

}

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetID, batchUpdateRequest).execute();
```

**Error log:**

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid requests[0].updateCells: Attempting to write column: 26, beyond the last requested column of: 25",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid requests[0].updateCells: Attempting to write column: 26, beyond the last requested column of: 25",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at main.java.Quickstart.fillRowAndColumnHeadings(Quickstart.java:143)
    at main.java.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

I am not sure if there is any default number of columns set for Google Sheets and if so, how can I override the default value? Basically I want to create a google spreadsheet with columns as Dates of a month (in above example, dates of month November), and rows as hour timestamps. Any inputs / pointers for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The request looks OK from a client perspective. This is likely a bad error message from the server.  Are you sure the sheet has enough columns in it?  The error should probably say the # of columns in the sheet is fewer than the column requested.

Comment: My google spreadsheet is currently blank, and I wanted to fill it in by first filling the column headers in the first row.. The for loop is for that purpose. Is the number of columns limited in a blank spreadsheet?

Answer (score 6):

You have to extend the number of columns with "appendDimension" API.

See documentation here (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#append_empty_rows_or_columns)

```
Request request = new Request();
AppendDimensionRequest appendRequest = new AppendDimensionRequest();
appendRequest .setDimension("COLUMNS");
appendRequest .setLength(50);
request .setAppendDimension(appendRequest );

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest request = new  BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(Arrays.asList((request ));
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response =  sheetsService.spreadsheets()
            .batchUpdate(sheetId, request)
            .execute();
```

Comment: You can also use `AppendCellsRequest` which not only append the dimension as add the data as well. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest

Answer (score 1):

Debugged a little -- I think this is a mix of user error & server error.  The server error is we seem to give the wrong error message in the case where the input size is > 1 and the extra input goes beyond the edge of the grid.  The user error is you seem to be collecting your `values` into a var whose lifetime is outside the loop, but are re-using it in each Request in the loop, causing subsequent Requests to write more than expected.  There are two possible solutions:

1) Make a new `values` var each time you loop, rather than appending new values to the prior ones & re-writing them.

or 2) Append into the `values` var, but only make a single `Request` whose values is the combined values of each column you want to write.